# i'm getting this error: uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

i have the code belowin the environment.rb and i keep getting the error uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE (NameError) when i try to run it.

### environment.rb

```
require 'yaml' 
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
Quora::Application.initialize!
```

anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you specify your Ruby versions as well as Rails?

Comment: Ruby v- 1.8.7 and Rails v- 3.0.5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

YAML::ENGINE doesn't exist in Ruby 1.8.7. This is defined in Ruby 1.9. I tried running irb on 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. Strange though, both of their YAML version number is the same (0.6.0).

Also, I think Ruby 1.8.7's YAML already uses SYCK for yaml parsing. :)

Comment: Use `YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck' if defined?(YAML::ENGINE)` to make it not blow up under 1.8.7.

Comment: Good point Andrew! Although I must say I prefer using RVM and avoiding to try and make the project work in 2 versions. This is not always the case though, so I agree... if it's just a Ruby 1.8.7 project, the line's not needed, but if he needed the project run in (for e.g.) 1.9.2 and 1.8.7, that's the way to go.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm's comment should actually be the accepted answer since it actually solves the problem rather than simply explaining it.